# strange graph with gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a problem with a curve fitting in gnuplot with my data:

If I use these commands:

```
plot "sky.txt"
f(x)=A*exp(-(t)/(sin(x)))+B

fit f(x) "sky.txt" u 1:2 via A,t,B
plot "sky.txt", f(x)
```

Then I get strange results, like errors of +- 1093%
When I'm plotting this I get a very strange plot.

This is measured data. I have no idea what's wrong in here.
Thank you for help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! `x` seems to be your independent variable and you want to fit an exponential decay. So, are you sure your function shouldn't be something like: `f(x)=A*exp(-(x)/(sin(t)))+B`? Please provide the data if you want it to be reproduced and tested.

Comment: -t is the variable that i search. A and B are irrelevant for further calculation. Thanks I posted the data below.

Comment: I assume `x` is the angle and it should be in degrees?! If yes, then you have to tell gnuplot `set angle degrees`. Check `help angles`. Default is radians.

Comment: thank you!!! that was the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... the comment again as answer, according to the StackOverflow "rule": no answers in comments!

You have to set the angles to degrees via: (check `help angles`). Default is radians.

```
set angles degrees
```